# Separate projects for Microsoft.Build.Utilities, Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v3.5, Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, msbuild-task

I created a custom build task DLL that References Microsoft.Build.Utilities.dll

Since the file name is different in each version,

do I need to create separate project files to target different MSBuild versions?
2.0, 3.5, 4.0 / 4.5

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do that. If you build your projects from the code, you should be able to set `GlobalProperty` for every property you can find in .csproj file. The proper MSBuild version will be choosed automatically.

```
     ProjectCollection pc = new ProjectCollection();
     Dictionary<string, string> GlobalProperty = new Dictionary<string, string>();

     //GlobalProperty.Add("Configuration", "Debug");
     //GlobalProperty.Add("Platform", "x86");
     //GlobalProperty.Add("OutputPath", "c:\\src");
     //GlobalProperty.Add("TargetFrameworkVersion", "4.0");

     BuildRequestData buidlRequest = new BuildRequestData("projectfile.csproj", GlobalProperty, null, new string[] { "Build" }, null);
     BuildResult buildResult = BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.Build(new BuildParameters(pc), buidlRequest);

     //if (buildResult["Build"].ResultCode == TargetResultCode.Success)
     //{
     //   Console.WriteLine("Build Success");
     //}
     //else
     //{
     //   Console.WriteLine("Build Fail");
     //}
```